# Метод fetchone() возвращает NoneType

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, re, psycopg2

В базе данных указан Data type - text. По логике вещей он должен возвращать string, но почему-то возвращает NoneType и выскакивает соответствующая ошибка "expected string or bytes-like object".

```
import psycopg2
from auth_data import host, password, db_name, user
import re

connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name)
pattern = r"'(.*?)'"

try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT game FROM game_users WHERE id_tg = 5916961134;")
        connection.commit()
        string = cursor.fetchone()
        print(re.findall(pattern, string))
except Exception as _ex:
    print(f'[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL {_ex}')
finally:
    if connection:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print(f'[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')
```

Жду ваших решений!

P.S. база данных - PostgreSQL, если это играет какую-то роль.

P.S.S Пишу это дополнения, как доказательство тому, что в результате есть строка.

```
import psycopg2
from auth_data import host, password, db_name, user

connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name)

try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT game FROM game_users WHERE id_tg = 5916961134;")
        connection.commit()
        print(f'[INFO] String is {cursor.fetchone()}')
except Exception as _ex:
    print(f'[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL {_ex}')
finally:
    if connection:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print(f'[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')
```

Вывод:

```
[INFO] String is ('Minecraft',)
[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed
```

Comment: Первый fetchone возвращает первую строку результата, второй fetchone возвращает вторую строку результата. Если в результате строка всего одна и вы её уже забрали первым fetchone, то вполне логично, что второй fetchone ничего не вернёт

Comment: @andreymal, внес правки, где убрал второй fetchone. Но ничего не изменилось. Все та же ошибка

Comment: Ну тогда это может означать, что в результате вообще нет строк. Вы точно уверены, что строки вообще должны быть?

Comment: @andreymal, опять же внес правки, где добавил вывод. Посмотрите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему таким образом, даже не используя регулярные выражения. всем спасибо за помощь!

```
import psycopg2
from auth_data import host, password, db_name, user

connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT game FROM game_users WHERE id_tg = 5916961134;")
        connection.commit()
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        string = result[0]
        print(string.strip("('')"))
except Exception as _ex:
    print(f'[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL: {_ex}')
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
        print(f'[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод `fetchone` возвращает кортеж (tuple) или None, если нет данных.
Вы пытаетесь применить регулярное выражение `re.findall` к кортежу.

Вам нужно получить первый элемент из кортежа (строку), а затем применить регулярное выражение к этой строке

```
import psycopg2
from auth_data import host, password, db_name, user
import re

connection = psycopg2.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=db_name)
pattern = r"'(.*?)'"

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT game FROM game_users WHERE id_tg = 5916961134;")
        connection.commit()
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result:
            string = result[0]
            print(re.findall(pattern, string[0]))
        else:
            print("No data found.")
except Exception as _ex:
    print(f'[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL: {_ex}')
finally:
    if connection:
        connection.close()
        print(f'[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, что отметил ответ, как верный, на эмоциях не понял кое-чего. После вашей программы вывод таков: `[]`
`[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed`

Comment: Перепроверил тип у переменной string, все так же `<class 'tuple'>`

Comment: Немного откорректировал. Попробуйте вновь.

Comment: вывод остался точно таким же.